# MICE - Single variable/parameter estimate

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I'm running MICE on my dataset and have set the predictor matrix and have M estimates, but I wish to get a pooled value for a single estimate, instead of multiple through a linear model as shown in the MICE documentation. However, I'm unsure of how to achieve this, would anyone have any advice?

For example, for multiple estimates I may carry out the following (where give_imp is the result of my 12 imputed datasets)

```
library(mice)
library(tidyverse)
give_imp_fit_t <- with(give_imp, lm(var_1 ~ var_2))

give_pool_t <- mice::pool(give_imp_fit_t)
summary(give_pool_t, conf.int = TRUE) %>%
   tibble::as_tibble() %>%
   dplyr::mutate(
     dplyr::across(where(is.numeric), ~round(., 3))
   )
```

What would I do if I wanted to gain estimates for var_1 only?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, I was being silly, it's var_1 ~ 1 in the lm function!